# Fn keys do not work while playing games in full screen

Tags: games, fullscreen

When I play a game such as OpenArena, AssaultCube or OpenTTD, I cannot use Fn keys such as to decrease/increase volume. The only possibility to use is playing in window mode.

How can I enable those keys in Fullscreen mode as well?

Comment: Changing Shortcut Keys of Sound and Media would help you.. Since the process was so long I thought it to post as an answer.. Give it a try, hope it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this option. You'll get a lot of configuration to set your own `Shortcut Key` for `Sound and Media`.

Follow these steps:

- Open `Keyboard` from `System Settings` (Search in *dash*)
- Chose <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> tab
- Go to `Sound and Media` you will get a bunch of options.
- I am attaching a screenshot which is my configuration. I changed to Sound Keys to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd> since I don't have multimedia keyboard and it works fine for me.

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/1238156_441720439281184_627443213_n.jpg))</sub>

Changing `Shortcut Keys` would help you somewhat! Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late answer. Actually I forgot to tell you that I am using Kubuntu desktop, but I also found Global Shortcuts settings for this. However, this didnt help:/